# wifi causing errors since kernel version 3.19 update

Tags: wifi, iwlwifi

I've been having issues with my latest Ubuntu 15.04 installation. Whenever the wifi changes on it's own, or I change it through the drop-down selection, my kernel panics -- my computer is unresponsive, all I can do is hard-stop it. Here's the output in syslog from that timespan.

```
May  8 14:42:35 odessa avahi-daemon[828]: Registering new address record for 2001:558:1400:4e:260a:64ff:fef5:7541 on wlan0.*.
    May  8 14:42:39 odessa ntpdate[13073]: no server suitable for synchronization found
    May  8 14:43:00 odessa wpa_supplicant[958]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
    ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@May  8 15:15:11 odessa rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="829" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
    May  8 15:15:11 odessa rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104
```

uname output:

```
Linux odessa 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Some of the errors that I'm seeing:

```
[ 1784.417066] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address, mac = 3c:ce:73:f7:b9:cc   profile =3c:ce:73:f7:b9:c3
[ 1784.417094] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address, mac = 3c:ce:73:f7:b9:cc   profile =3c:ce:73:f7:b9:c3

[  442.120676] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
[  442.120680] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)

ERROR @wl_inform_single_bss : cfg80211_inform_bss_frame error
```

wlan:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2154
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at b2600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Region 2: Memory at b2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Can  anyone suggest a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I have a macbook pro and had to install the BCM driver to get things to work correctly. If I remember correctly it was just a:

```
 apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

These pages may also provide some guidance:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx
https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: Doesn't help. I reverted back to 3.13 kernel and the same configuration started working without a glitch. It looks like a kernel compatibility issue. I'll stick with 14.04 LTS